# Suggestion inside XML Number Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing an app that involves getting input from the user, and so I want to be as minimalist as possible. I am looking for a way to place what should be written in a number box like this:

+----------------------------+

`Enter number of days`

+----------------------------+

in a grayed out manner, that dissapears when a number is placed inside.

I tried to google it, but since I couldn't find the right word (Not a native speaker), I couldn't find the right results. So I come here for help.

Comment: The word is "tip", sometimes they call it "tool tip" or "hint". In android it's a "hint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:hint="Enter number of days"`

```
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter number of days"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

See here for the  "hint" usage: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHint()